# fsolve error: no function or method found

Tags: octave

I wrote this code in octave:

```
syms z;
f=z-2;
fsolve("f",0.)
```

Then this gives the error

> @f: no function and no method found.

Also using `fsolve(@f,0)` gives the same error

When I write code as:

```
syms z;
f=z-2;
fsolve(f,0.)
```

Then this gives the error

> ind2sub: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals.

Please explain to me how to actually use `fsolve`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% syms z;      % Not needed, actually slows down the code
f=@(z)(z-2); 
fsolve(f,0.)
```

You're missing the `@` symbol, which is a function handle. This tells Octave that `f` is not a variable, but actually is a(n anonymous) function, in this case of `z`, which is the first argument.

You'll probably want to have `z` to be a regular variable, because making it symbolic turns MATLAB from a speeding race car to a drudging farm vehicle. Unless there's a specific reason to have `z` symbolic (I cant think of any in case of usage with `fsolve`)' it's best to avoid symbolic maths.