# why do i get fminsearch undefined function error

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, function-handle, fminsearch

I'm trying to optimize a function with 2 inputs. Trying to use fminsearch but it keeps saying undefined function or variable although it is already defined.

I have already defined the function in a separate script that is in the same directory with my main script. I have a classroom license which includes optimization toolbox and there is no spelling mistake while calling the function.

```
function o=u(x,y)  
%some code here
end

%in a second script

init=[0.1,0.1];

b=fminsearch(o,init);
```

The error is:

> Undefined function or variable 'o'.

Comment: Define `o` before using it. It's not defined anywhere in the code that you have shown here. You have defined a function `u` though

Comment: @SardarUsama in addition to that, they're lacking a function handle, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37890864/5211833)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [`fminsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html), the function being minimized must have a single argument and accessed with a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) (see this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37890864/8239061)).

The error you are getting is because you can't call `o` and use it as an input to `fminsearch()` since `o` is undefined.  To get `o`, you have to first get `u(x,y)`, plus as mentioned, `fminsearch` requires a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) as an input.

You have several options that still **use your standalone function**, `u(x,y)`.

**1. Create a function handle**
Define a function handle that calls `u(x,y)` but has a single argument which is a 2 x 1 vector, `z = [x; y]`.

```
fh =@(z) u(z(1),z(2));
z0 = [1; 2];                         % Initial Guess for z = [x; y]
[z,TC] = fminsearch(fh,z0)
```

**2. Change the function and call it directly**

The same result is possible with

```
[z,TC] = fminsearch(@u,z0)
```

if you redefine `u(x,y)` to be as follows:

```
function o=u(z) 
   x = z(1);
   y = z(2); 
   % your function code here
end
```